# How is this called? ("Syncing sequences")

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, terminology

I recently needed something like the following:

Let $(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_m)$ and $(b_0, b_1, \dots, b_n)$ be two
finite sequences of integers, not necessarily of the same length,
with the same beginning and end (i.e. $a_0 = b_0$ and $a_m =
b_n$) and both with the property that the difference between two
successive sequence elements is always $1$ or $-1$, i.e. $|a_k -
a_{k+1}| = 1$ for $k=0,\dots,m-1$ and the same for the other
sequence.  Furthermore, let each sequence only have elements
between the beginning and the end.  To be more precise, we demand
$$\min(a_0,a_m) < a_k < \max(a_0,a_m)$$ for $k=1,\dots,m-1$ and
the same for the other sequence.

It is then always possible to construct a finite sequence
  $$ ((\alpha_0,\beta_0), (\alpha_1,\beta_1), \dots, (\alpha_r,\beta_r)) $$
of pairs of indices such that the following conditions hold:

- $0 \leq \alpha_k \leq m$ for $k=0,\dots,r$
- $0 \leq \beta_k \leq n$ for $k=0,\dots,r$
- $(\alpha_0,\beta_0) = (0,0)$
- $(\alpha_r,\beta_r) = (m,n)$
- $|\alpha_k - \alpha_{k+1}| = 1$ for $k=0,\dots,r-1$
- $|\beta_k - \beta_{k+1}| = 1$ for $k=0,\dots,r-1$
- $a_{\alpha_k} = b_{\beta_k}$ for $k=0,\dots,r$

(This is easier to visualize than to write down.  See for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pciTdzxGueU).)

I was able to prove this and to also code a recursive algorithm for this.

**My question now is:** This must surely be something that people have done before.  But how is it called?  I was unable to find a name for this.  I don't even know how to tag this question correctly...

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that this *exact* thing has been done before. I'd call it "skip-zipping" the sequences together, because you're zipping, but possibly skipping some terms in between.

Comment: You might want to look at 1-d random walks bounded between two points? You might stumble onto something similar

Comment: This sounds a lot like a discrete version of the mountain climbing problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_climbing_problem

Comment: @SteveKass: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.  If you make an answer out of your comment, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Moved from comments at OP’s request]

This sounds a lot like a discrete version of [the mountain climbing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_climbing_problem).